# Broken anchor link Wordpress

Tags: html, wordpress, anchor

The problem page is : http://www.redrocketwebsitedesign.co.uk/the-wiltshire.co.uk/membership#golf-membership

I have an issue with the links at the top of the post. Clicking on `Golf Membership` should take the page down a bit to the Golf membership section, the same thing should happen with `Leisure Membership`.

I don't seem to have these problems on another page with anchor links : http://www.redrocketwebsitedesign.co.uk/the-wiltshire.co.uk/junior-golf

Does anyone know what could be the issue?

Comment: You have two elements with the ID `golf-membership`. Each ID should be unique.

Comment: sidenote: @Krishna please provide better edits next time. You might find [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts) useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ids for anchor links should be unique. But for example you have two identical ids for golf-membership on line 304 and line 629. For some reason you have duplicate code.

And for leisure-membership you have one id, but two hrefs on line 303.

One duplicate code starts at 301

```
<h1>Become a member at The Wiltshire</h1>
```

And then again at line 626.

```
<h1>Become a member at The Wiltshire</h1>
```

But only one of them is displayed in the browser, no idea why.

I use Firefox to display source code and then find duplicates.

Comment: Hello ed-ta, Thanks, that's right. I'll fix this :-]